# How to choose the right storage technology and design for a tree like date structure that requires fast reads

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I have a requirement to design a tree like data structure whereby child entities can inherit or override values from parent entities.

- client

  - entity
  - - channel

If you could imagine three above entities with client being at level 0, entity at level 1 and channel at level 2. The entity level items can inherit or override attributes from the client level and channels can inherit or override attributes from their entity level parents.

I also need the channel to be sub-sectioned into groups where each channel can be valid from a specific dateTime. So if I make a query to get a specific channel I will pass current instance of time and I will need to get back the top first item which is less than the input datetime parameter.

Hopefully the tree's depth will be set at 3 and there won't be any extensions. My question is what would be the best approach for designing this data structure.

Should I have 3 tables for each type and have a view that is designed to allow for fast access to the data, or should I have a single table and use one of the three tree design methodologies described in this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/anthonybloesch/2006/02/15/hierarchies-trees-in-sql-server-2005/)?

What would be the upside and downside of each approach?

Comment: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless *you* define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Noting the Relational database tag</sub>

The *Relational Model* handles hierarchies beautifully.  There is no need to do strange things, such as in the blog post: it is anti-Relational.  The hierarchy is implemented plainly, and all queries are simple.  Use SQL, the data sub-language for the *RM*, to obtain whatever "picture" or "view" you need of the data.

- If you want Relational, definitely three tables: one table would be horrendous because it is not Normalised.
- The Primary Keys I am giving you (`Client`, `Entity`, `Channel`) are short names or codes that the user has for Identifying their data. In the second and third tables, they are composites.  Such Keys are very fast.

  - ie. it is not a surrogate, such as a `Record ID, ID, id`.  A surrogate is always an **additional** column and an **additional** index, which would make the tables distinctly slower.  Not to mention, the code required will be buggy and confusing.
- This is adequate for the level of your question, the SQL code required to navigate the structure is simple.
- To cater for the "inheritance or override" of the attributes, I can provide a more Normalised design, which will have no NULL columns, however it will require slightly more complex SQL code, which can be eased with the use of a **View**.  Please ask.

### Relational Data Model

[image: XerxesTA]

#### Note • Notation

- All my data models are rendered in **[IDEF1X](https://www.idef.com/idef1x-data-modeling-method/)**, the Standard for modelling Relational databases since 1993
- My **[IDEF1X Introduction](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Introduction.pdf)** is essential reading for beginners.

Enjoy.